# Pandas convert numbers with a comma instead of the point for the decimal separator from objects to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im my dataframe I have a column with numbers a format with the comma as separator, like `0,5` and the data type inferred is object. I need to convert them to numbers, but when I try
`df['ColumnName'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ColumnName'])` I get the following exception:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "2,55"
```

I tried looking on google and so, but couldn't find a solution. The `to_numeric` method's signature does not allow to specify a separator.

Any ideas on how could I fix the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace `,` with `.`:

```
df['ColumnName'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ColumnName'].str.replace(',', '.'))
```

On the other note, if you read the data with `pd.read_csv`, there's an option `decimal=','`.

Comment: The second option will cause still problems because in another column the dot is used.